# Swift Make For Loop wait for Asynchronous function to end

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

im trying to work with firebase, i made this function that is saving "Offers" to an Array and then sending this array to another viewcontroller to show them on a tableView.

i found a problem that the for loop is ending before the data is coming from the servers and the callback of firebase is coming, where u can see the line "fir (self.goodOffer...)" is the end of the firebase callback.

maybe someone know how can i make the for loop to wait for the firebase callback to end?

thx.

```
 geocodeAddress(totalFromLocation, callback: { (location) in

                if location != nil {
                    fromLocation = location
                    self.geocodeAddress(totalToLocation, callback: { (location) in
                        if location != nil {
                            toLocation = location
                            mainDistance = Int(self.distanceCalculate(fromLocation!, locationTwo: toLocation!))
                            print(mainDistance)

                            REF_BUSSINES_OFFERS.queryOrderedByKey().queryEqualToValue("north").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                                print("in snap")
                                if let value = snapshot.value {
                                    if self.isAlavator {
                                        if let area = value["north"] {
                                            if let data = area!["withAlavator"]! {
                                                if let bids = data["bids"] as? Int {
                                                    for i in 1..<bids+1 {
                                                        if let bid = data["\(i)"] {
                                                            let bidFromSize = bid!["fromSize"] as! Int
                                                            let bidToSize = bid!["toSize"] as! Int

                                                            let bidFromDistance = bid!["fromDistance"] as! Int
                                                            let bidToDistance = bid!["toDistance"] as! Int

                                                            if mainDistance >= bidFromDistance && mainDistance <= bidToDistance {
                                                                if Int(totalSize) >= bidFromSize && Int(totalSize) <= bidToSize {
                                                                    let price = String(bid!["price"])
                                                                    let name = bid!["name"] as! String
                                                                    let phoneNumber = bid!["phoneNumber"] as! String
                                                                    var logoImageData: NSData!
                                                                    LOGOS_REF.child("\(phoneNumber)").dataWithMaxSize(3 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                                                                        if error != nil {
                                                                            logoImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "company")!)
                                                                        } else {
                                                                            logoImageData = data
                                                                        }
                                                                        let offer = Offer(logoImage: logoImageData, name: name, price: price)
                                                                        self.goodOffers.append(offer)
                                                                        print("fir \(self.goodOffers[0].price)")
                                                                    })
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        print(i)
                                                    }//end of for
                                                    print("out")
                                                    //self.changgeViewToTable()
                                                }
```

Comment: Good grief, your code is running off the side of the screen. Doesn't switch have `return` or something so you could return early instead of nesting your things who knows how many levels deep? (Also what's an "alavator"?)

Comment: You should post this to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) when you fixed the error, your code is nightmare material

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't help you much because your code is such a pain to read. Use `ObjectMapper` to reduce the level (and the effort) to map these fields. Anyhow, you can use `dispatch_group` to synchronize the various async calls:

```
let group = dispatch_group_create()
for i in 1..<bids+1 {
    // ...
    dispatch_group_enter(group)
    LOGOS_REF.child("\(phoneNumber)").dataWithMaxSize(3 * 1024 * 1024) {
        // ...

        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }
}    

// Wait for all async calls to complete before proceeding
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

Each `dispatch_group_enter()` should be balanced with a `dispatch_group_leave()` when the async task is complete.

Comment: I don't really know where you got this code out of OPs question, but you probably intended the `dispatch_group_wait` to be after the `for` loop, so all calls run asynchronously

Comment: @Kametrixom good eyes. I moved the `dispatch_group_wait` to outside the `for` loop. Thanks!

Comment: @CodeDifferent `dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.changgeViewToTable() }` would better than `dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)`.

Comment: @JefferyThomas thank you very much your answer fixed code differnt answer